# Custom MPAndroidChart for Android

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using this library https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart for making a bar chart in my project, I have tried and follow the wiki but still cannot figure some of the problems I have left. I am trying to remove the values (4,3,2,1,0) on the right and the label "BarDataSet"below along with the color block on the left. And finally the color I tried to set on the bars aren't what I defined.

what I  have done:

```
    List<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
    entries.add(new BarEntry(0f, 55f));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(1f, 80f));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(2f, 60f));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(3f, 50f));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(4f, 40f));

    BarDataSet set = new BarDataSet(entries, "BarDataSet");
    BarData data = new BarData(set);
    data.setBarWidth(0.9f); // set custom bar width
    barChart.setData(data);
    barChart.setFitBars(true); // make the x-axis fit exactly all bars
    barChart.invalidate(); // refresh
    barChart.getAxisLeft().setEnabled(false);
    barChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
    barChart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
    barChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
    set.setColors(R.color.star_bar);
```

And what I have now:

[image: Result]

I would like to remove the labels on the right(4 to 0) and "BarDataSet".
The color I defined for R.color.star_bar is yellow but somehow it is showing a purple color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the line:

```
set.setColors(R.color.star_bar);
```

Then, you have to add below lines:

```
   barChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false); // hide the legend
    set.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent)); // set yellow color

    // hide the labels
    barChart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new IAxisValueFormatter() {
        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {

            return "";
        }
    });
```

Comment: I think setting barChart.getXAxis().setDrawLabels(false);, would be better than making value formatter return "".

Answer (score 0):

If the Right side 0 to 4 are the bar values, to remove them set :

```
data.setDrawValues(false);
```

else if they are the lables then try:

```
barChart.getXAxis().setDrawLabels(false);
```

And the "BarDataSet" is the legend, which you can hide using:

```
 barChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
```

And one more thing in your code is that you are invalidating chart first and then setting some properties, But I think its always better to invalidate chart at end, so place below line at end and try:

```
barChart.invalidate();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply,  barChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false) worked ideally, however the 0 to 4 at the right side are not bar values as you can see in my image there are still values for 0. I think they are positions whenever I am adding the entries, the 0f to 4f ? And thank you for the reminder for barChart.invalidate()